# Relative frequencies/proportions with dplyr create new columns instead of rows

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, frequency

This question is inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24576515/relative-frequencies-proportions-with-dplyr) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44256239/compute-relative-frequencies-with-group-totals-using-dplyr) question.

I am trying to calculate the proportion of different values within each group, but I do not want to create "new" rows for the groups but new columns.

Taking the example from the second question above. If I have the following data:

```
data <- structure(list(value = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), class = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("A", 
"B"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("value", "class"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
```

I can calculate the proportion of each value (1,2,3) in each class (A,B):

```
data %>%
    group_by(value, class) %>%
    summarise(n = n()) %>%
    complete(class, fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
    group_by(class) %>%
    mutate(freq = n / sum(n))
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  value  class     n      freq
  <int> <fctr> <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1      A     3 0.2727273
2     1      B     3 0.6000000
3     2      A     4 0.3636364
4     2      B     2 0.4000000
5     3      A     4 0.3636364
6     3      B     0 0.0000000
```

However I end up with a line for each value/class pair instead I want something like this:

```
# some code
# A tibble: 6 x 4
   class     n      1        2         3
  <fctr> <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
1    A     11 0.2727273  0.3636364  0.3636364
2    B     5  0.6000000  0.4000000  0.0000000
```

With a column for each group. I could write for loops to construct a new data frame from the old one but I am certain there is a better way. Any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `pivot_wider` at the end

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>%
    group_by(value, class) %>%
    summarise(n = n()) %>%
    complete(class, fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
    group_by(class) %>%
    mutate(freq = n / sum(n), n = sum(n)) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = freq)
# A tibble: 2 x 5
# Groups:   class [2]
#  class     n   `1`   `2`   `3`
#  <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 A        11 0.273 0.364 0.364
#2 B         5 0.6   0.4   0
```

Or as @IcecreamToucan mentioned, the `complete` is not needed as the `pivot_wider` have the option to fill with a custom value (default is NA)

```
data %>% 
    group_by(value, class) %>% 
    summarise(n = n()) %>%  
    group_by(class) %>%
    mutate(freq = n / sum(n), n = sum(n)) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = freq, values_fill = list(freq = 0))
```

If we are using a previous version of `tidyr`, then use `spread`

```
data %>%
    group_by(value, class) %>%
    summarise(n = n()) %>%
    complete(class, fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
    group_by(class) %>%
    mutate(freq = n / sum(n), n = sum(n)) %>% 
    spread(value, freq)
```

Comment: I will look into pivot_wider. (I am fairly new to R).

Comment: So this looks like it is exactly what I want, but it is telling me `could not find function "pivot_wider"`. My version of tidyr is 0.8.3 so maybe I need to update it. I will work more on this after my next meeting.

Comment: @goryh  It is from `tidyr`.  I used `packageVersion('tidyr')#
[1] ‘1.0.0’`

Answer (score 2):

Method using `data.table::dcast` instead of `pivot_wider`.

Line 1: Get a count (`.N`) for each (value, class) group, and call it `n`

Line 2: Make new variables within each `class` group:

- `N`, the sum of the previous counts
- `pct`, the percent of `N` each `n` makes up

Line 3: Cast to wide with `class` and `N` as the rows, `value` as the column names, and `pct` as the column elements, with empty elements set to 0.

```
library(magrittr) # For %>%. Not necessary if dplyr is loaded already
library(data.table)
setDT(data)

data[, .(n = .N), by = .(value, class)] %>% 
    .[, `:=`(N = sum(n), pct = n/sum(n)), by = class] %>% 
  dcast(class + N ~ value, value.var = 'pct', fill = 0)

#    class  N         1         2         3
# 1:     A 11 0.2727273 0.3636364 0.3636364
# 2:     B  5 0.6000000 0.4000000 0.0000000
```

Comment: Thank you. Another priority has come up so I do not have time to try your answer yet.

Answer (score 0):

We can use  `count` to count occurrences of `value` and `class`, `group_by` `class`, calculate the frequency and get the data in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>%
  count(value, class) %>%
  group_by(class) %>%
  mutate(freq = n/sum(n), n = sum(n)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = freq, values_fill = list(freq = 0))

# class     n   `1`   `2`   `3`
#  <fct> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 A        11 0.273 0.364 0.364
#2 B         5 0.6   0.4   0
```

Comment: This looks to be the same as akrun's asnwer.

Comment: @goryh I haven't used `group_by` + `summarise` and instead replaced it with `count`.

Comment: Ah I did not look close enough the first time.